# Как поменять значения в списке, не создавая новый список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Стандартный способ через списковое включение (`list comprehension`):

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_list_1=[i*5 for i in my_list]
print(my_list_1)
```

Почему не могу сделать также с исходным списком:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in my_list:
    i*=5
print(my_list)
```

Этот код не работает, почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для данной конструкции:

```
for i in my_list:
    i*=5
```

Python создает новую переменную `i` в которую попадают последовательно значения из списка. В итоге вы меняете значения переменной `i`, список остается неизменным.

```
In [136]: my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
     ...: for i in my_list:
     ...:     i*=5
     ...:     print(i, my_list)
     ...:
5 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
10 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
15 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
20 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
25 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
30 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

В следующей строке кода вы присваиваете переменной `my_list_1` результат работы `list comprehension` (список):

```
my_list_1=[i*5 for i in my_list]
```

---

Решение:

```
my_list[:] = [i*5 for i in my_list]
print(my_list)
#[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

PS подробнее о присвоениях спискам и срезах можно прочитать в [ответах на этот вопрос в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ и разъяснение темы!

Comment: @НикитаШиляев, всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Тут список копируется, переменные не меняются инплэйс

Comment: @eri, напишите свой ответ, если можете дать более точный, более полный/развернутый ответ. Это будет полезно для сообщества...

Comment: Ваш ответ вполне корректен и даже оптимален для списков меньше пары десятков мегабайт.  Вопрос просто странно стоит. На изменение значения в ячейке внутри списка или внутри переменной. Что важнее для автора: результат или процесс?

Comment: То что я имел ввиду уже написал gil9red)

Answer (score 6):

Вы можете менять значение элемента списка, но вам нужно знать его индекс, для этого используются следующие способы:

Через `range`:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = my_list[i] * 5
print(my_list)  # [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

Через `enumerate`:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[i] = x * 5
print(my_list)  # [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

---

**PS.**

А код с списковым включением:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_list_1=[i*5 for i in my_list]
print(my_list_1)  # [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

тоже самое что:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_list_1=[]
for i in my_list:
    my_list_1.append(i * 5)
print(my_list_1)  # [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

Comment: большое спасибо за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Через небольшие костыли. Можно через команду .insert ввести место, где нужно поменять значение и сразу удалить, что там уже стояло, и уже измененное что либо вставить:

```
spisok = []
mesto = int(input())
spisok.pop(mesto)
i = input()
spisok.insert(mesto, i)
```